# Not able to read from stdout

Tags: c, stdout

I am trying read `stdout` of my own program into 2 arrays like this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char arr[100]={0};
    char arr2[100]={0};

    printf("Hello world\n"); // This writes to stdout

    fgets( arr, 80, stdout );

    fseek ( stdout, 0, SEEK_SET );

    fgets ( arr2, 80, stdout );
    printf ("First array is %s\n", arr );
    printf ("Second array is %s\n", arr2 );

    return 0;

}
```

The output is not what I expect. That is both the arrays are empty instead of containing `Hello World` as I expected.

I went through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228219/read-the-stdout-from-the-same-c-program) which suggests dealing with pipes to accomplish what I want but **doesn't tell me** why my above code doesn't work?

**EDIT:** Though it would be nice to know alternatives to make the above work as it should, I am more curious on the problems involved in reading `stdout` of the same program

Comment: To suggest alternative, you need to tell us what do you need this for and why. Are you trying to simulate `/usr/bin/tee`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every file is seekable, readable or writeable. Stdout is usually a kind that can't be read back.

Most likely, `stdout` will be a pipe. In that case, your program holds the writable end, and someone else holds the readable end. The pipe implementation just transfers data and does not keep it; once it has been read at the other end, there is no way to get it back.

If you want a file that can be read back, create a regular temporary file, or your own pipe, and use `fprintf`/`fscanf` instead of `printf`/`scanf`. Alternatively, do `freopen` on stdout to reassign it to another file/pipe, then `printf` will operate on that new file.

Comment: I cant completely agree with you on your first assertion. If `stdout` cant be read back then how does the shell show up the output of other programs? The problem seems to arise when we read `stdout` of the same program.
Also, I am aware of the alternatives, but I wanted to know why this particular method doesn't work.

Comment: @Stacker `stdout` is usually a pipe. The shell holds the end that can only be read from, and your program holds the end that can only be written to. `stdin` is set up exactly the opposite way.

Comment: @Stacker In fact, shell does not even read output of programs. It connects terminal to their stdout (or to a file, if you use `>redirection`, or to stdin of another program if you use `| piping`) and whatever is printed goes directly to that terminal device, file or program. Shell may have already exited by that time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifications @hamstergene. I dint know stdout acted as a pipe. I always thought it was a file and if so why couldn't we read it from the same program. I'll try reading more about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
char arr[100]={0};
char arr2[100]={0};
int i,j;

printf("Hello world\n"); // This writes to stdout

fgets( arr, 80, stdin );

fgets ( arr2, 80, stdin );
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i<80; i++){
    printf ("%c", arr[i]);
}
for(j=0; j<80; j++){
    printf ("%c", arr2[j]);
}

return 0;
}
```

1) fgets has to read from stdin and not from stdout :)
2) you cannot print all the array with `printf array`, you **must** iterate into it with a `for` cicle

Comment: Well, in this case he is reading strings, so he can use `%s` to write them also. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use gotoxy, its a very simple command where you place coordinates of the position of the stdout.

```
COORD coord={0,0};
void gotoxy(int x,int y){
   coord.X=x;coord.Y=y;
   SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),coord);
}
```